# Use of genitive in Преступление и наказание

Tags: литература, родительный-падеж

The following quote is from the beginning of Part 1, chapter 7 (Раскольников stands at the old woman's door):

"...и опять два вострые и недоверчивые взгяда уставились на него из темноты."

Why is "вострые и недоверчивые" in nominative? Does 'два' not govern a genitive singular?

How can one person (in this case the old woman) look with "two glances" ("два взгляда")? Can "взгляд" be a synonym for "глаз"?

Comment: Could be archaic... In modern Russian it should be `...два острых и недоверчивых вздляда...`.

Comment: Adjecives in Genetive dual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is "вострые и недоверчивые" in nominative? Does 'два' not govern a genitive singular?

It does govern sg. gen. for nouns, but may govern both gen. and nom. for the adjectives defining them.

Rosenthal et al., #193.1:

> 1. При существительных мужского и среднего рода, зависящих от числительных *два, три, четыре* (а также от составных числительных, оканчивающихся на указанные цифры), определение, находящееся между числительным и существительным, в современном языке ставится, как правило, в форме родительного падежа множественного числа: *два высоких дома, три больших окна, двадцать четыре деревянных стола.*

Note the remark about "modern language" and "usually".

This graph: http://goo.gl/P1EoA shows decline in usage of nominative over time.

> How can one person (in this case the old woman) look with "two glances" ("два взгляда")? Can "взгляд" be a synonym for "глаз"?

Yes, it's a metonymy, and Dostoevsky is known for wide usage of those.

> … возбуждало в нем желчь и конвульсии (*желчь* instead of *разлитие желчи*)
>
> … cестра моя скорее в негры пойдет к плантатору или в латыши к остзейскому немцу … (*негры* and *латыши* instead of *батраки* or *рабы*)
>
> В другой расположились музыканты: две скрипки, флейта и контрбас. (instruments instead of players)